# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to integrate spring 3.1.1 with hibernate 4.0. This is my dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="com.future.controllers" />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.future.services.menu" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.future.dao" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bar_visitor2" p:username="root"
    p:password=""/>
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>


</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

When I try to use `@Transactional` annotation I am getting an error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor`.

I checked my classpath and there is `TransactionInterceptor.class`. What am I doing wrong? Should I add something?

**Edit**
This is my lib folder:

[image]

Comment: Do you also have `spring-aop*.jar` and `spring-beans*.jar` on the CLASSPATH?

Comment: as I emphasized in my answer - you have to check your _runtime_ classpath. What you show us is your compile-time classpath.

Comment: I solved the problem by downloading differnet jars.

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate your solution a bit? I'm running into the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your *runtime* classpath (i.e. WEB-INF/lib) for `spring-tx-...jar` (and make sure you have only one such jar, not many with different versions)

Comment: I checked it before and that's not it.

Comment: the exceptions means either that, or that you have more than one jar containing the interceptor, which confuses the classloader