# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor?

Tags: java, xml, spring, transactions

I have included the spring-tx jar but still i am getting the following exception  **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor**  Help!

Comment: it might help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009183/getting-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-transactio

Comment: which ide do you use? and the project is a java project or maven?
In any case your jar isn't in the classpath

Comment: i am using eclipse juno. project is a java project. i have included the jar in my WEB-INF/lib but still it shows this error  **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor**