# spring + hibernate web application

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I have started Web Application using Spring + Hibernate MVC. I Created All File. There are some issues when i'm debug my application. Here I have attached test-servlet.xml. First one is that how to add'  ' then there are 3 errors when i'm debug my application. I have also mentioned that error line. So any one help me plz on this???

**error :**

```
![javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet test threw exception

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource \[/WEB-INF/config/test-servlet.xml\]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please show what dependencies you are using?

Comment: This post could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261014/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-springframework-transaction-interceptor-tran

Answer (score 0):

The exception says:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor
```

Check your WEB-INF/lib and make sure you have the spring jar file that contains this class.

Answer (score 0):

This class is found in ["spring-tx"](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx) jar that should be present in your classpath (lib). Please check this. If not present please download appropriate version from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx).

Answer (score 0):

Download the `org.springframework.transaction.jar` and add add it to your classpath.